# Is it possible to obtain predictions on the training data from resample results?

Tags: mlr3

After executing the code below, it is possible to obtain predictions on the testing partition by using `rr$predictions()[[1]]`. But is it possible to obtain the predictions on the training partition?

```
task = tsk("penguins")
learner = lrn("classif.rpart")
resampling = rsmp("holdout")
rr = resample(task, learner, resampling)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `predict_sets` field of learner to both train and test, like this:

```
learner$predict_sets=c("test", "train")
```

Keep everything else the same and get train set predictions with

```
rr$prediction("train")
```